# Using percentage width works well in Firefox and not so well in Chrome, why?

Tags: css

I'm setting the width of an object to 705%. This works well in Firefox, but chrome seems to ignore the 5 part and renders it just like it was 700%.

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

All the bars have percentage width like 705%, 603.8%, but Chrome seems to ignore the "Small numbers"

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Can you post your code or a jsFiddle?

Comment: That shouldnt of been an answer- just an article - http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/

Comment: Looks the same to me except Chrome is missing the Edit button.

Comment: @Ray Cheng Look at the first four bars. They touch the right border in the first image, there's a little space between them and the border in the second image.

Answer (score 0):

Either live with the inconsistencies, round off your decimals if you can, or use a different unit size (ems work fine with decimals).  The problem with percentages has been around for quite some time.

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?547308-CSS-percentage-width-roundoff

Comment: Well in my case percentages are perfect, because if i resize the window the bars resize accordingly. I can't use ems or other things, if it's a know chrome bug, well, i'll leave them as they are and wait for chrome to fix it :)